# Add query to child form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been looking for some time now, but I can't see the problem here:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmd_Refresh_Click()

Dim sSQL_Select                     As String
Dim Qdb                             As Database
Dim Qry                             As QueryDef    

sSQL_Select = "SELECT * FROM T_TIME_SCHEDULE"

Set Qdb = CurrentDb
Set Qry = Qdb.CreateQueryDef("QTS", sSQL_Select)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QTS", acViewNormal
Me.F_Child_Result.Form.RecordSource = "QTS"
Me.F_Child_Result.Requery

Qdb.QueryDefs.Delete ("QTS")
Set Qdb = Nothing

End Sub
```

This line:

```
Me.F_Child_Result.Form.RecordSource = "QTS"
```

results in the following error:
**Run-Time error '2467': The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist.**
The syntax should be correctly constructed, and I double checked the name of the subform.
Desipte, the error remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not set the record source to a query, just the SQL string.

```
sSQL_Select = "SELECT * FROM T_TIME_SCHEDULE"

''Set Qdb = CurrentDb
''Set Qry = Qdb.CreateQueryDef("QTS", sSQL_Select)
''DoCmd.OpenQuery "QTS", acViewNormal
Me.F_Child_Result.Form.RecordSource = sSQL
''Me.F_Child_Result.Requery
```

There is no need to requery, the form will be requeried when the record source is changed.

Note that even if you could set the record source to a query (which you can't), it would not be quoted.

FROM Chat

It appears that there are two mixed strands in the question. What is required is a means to set the `Source Object` of the subform control to a query, not the `Record Source` of a form contained by the subform control.

The source object can be set like so:

```
Me.F_Child_Result.SourceObject="Query." & sQueryName
```

If the Source Object is already set to the name of a saved query that is used only for this form, there is no need to reset it, you can just modify the sql of the query:

```
Set qdf = CurrentDB.QueryDefs("JunkQuery")
qdf.SQL = sSQL
```

Comment: I'll try that when I'm back at my pc after lunch! I should have thought about that... thanks!

Comment: Tell you the honest truth, I get the same error (I think have tried it after all this morning)... It's as if it can't find the child form. It worked for you? I double checked the form name.

Comment: This is a common problem with subforms. The form name is the form contained by the subform control. You need the name of the subform control, not the form contained. They are frequently, but not always, the same.

Comment: You should be referring to Me=form code object --> subform control name --> form object contained by subform (unnamed) --> properties of form object.

Comment: Isn't this what it is... Me (form code object ).F_Child_Result (subform control name ).Form (unnamed).RecordSource (property) Perhaps I'm missing something here, but I don't see it.

Comment: You said you had checked the `form` name, not the subform control name. Is `F_Child_Result` returned by intellisense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14995/discussion-between-remou-and-kim-gysen)